# git init template, replacing modified hooks

Tags: git, githooks

I am constantly updating my local git hooks. I have a repo to house my .git template. This means that I am constantly running git init --template=../git-template to update repos with my hook changes.

Problem: Everytime I run git init --temp..., I need to first remove the hooks in .git/hooks that will be replaced with the updated hooks. This is annoying. I know I can script the removal of these hooks from the repo that I want to update, but is this functionality built into git already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I just symlink all my .git/hooks folders to a common location so I can just modify that; that might make your life easier

Comment: Good advice, never considered that. Thanks for the idea