# How to replace local git hooks with updated versions with git init?

Tags: git, githooks

I have exactly the same question as this user here:

[git init template, replacing modified hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007051/git-init-template-replacing-modified-hooks)

I have a new template file in my global git hooks. However, the original template file was already loaded, so `git init` does not overwrite. I read the same here, this appears to be the correct git behaviour:

From http://www.cs.potsdam.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+git-init:

> Running git init in an existing repository is safe. It will not
>   overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for
>   rerunning git init is to pick up newly added templates.

So what is a good way to force reloading new git template hooks? I have many hooks in many git repos, on several computers and used by a variety of users. The most practical way is to have the users run a specific command, rather than telling them to remove the hook first and then run the git init command. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The most practical way is to have the users run a specific command, rather than telling them to remove the hook first and then run the git init command

In that case, a possible way would be to distribute to those users a script which does just that (you could version that script in each of your repo).
Instead of doing the `git init` directly, they would call that script which would:

- remove the hooks
- call the `git init --template=`

---

But beware of the path you are using with the --temaplate option.
A relative `pathname` given to "`git init --template=<path> <repo>`"
ought to be relative to the directory "`git init`" gets invoked in,
but it instead was made relative to the repository, which has been
corrected with Git 2.22.1 (Q2 2019).

See [commit e1df7fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1df7fe43f4e2e607ed24668e2942d45df8d2743) (10 May 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 35d7715](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35d771591f673e1c2c7bc90b998670bed1e9e567), 25 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### init: make `--template` path relative to `$CWD`
>
> During `git-init` we `chdir()` to the target directory, but `--template` is
>   not adjusted.
>   So it's relative to the target directory instead of current directory.
>
> It would be ok if it's documented, but `--template` in `git-init.txt`
>   mentions nothing about this behavior.
>   Change it to be relative to `$CWD`, which is much more intuitive.